# C program to print sum of squares of digits of a given number?

Tags: c, sum, digits

I want to write a c program that prints the sum of the squares of a given number.
For example, if the given number is 456, the output would be 4^2+5^2+6^2=16+25+36=77.

So i have written this code and i want to know why it doesn't work if the user gives a number like 100,101,102 or 200,300 etc. It works fine for other numbers. I guess it has something to do with the dowhile loop. Please help me.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
main()
{
 int n,t=0,r,q;
 printf("Enter the number to be tested: ");
 scanf("%d",&n);
 q=n;
 do
 {
      r=q%10;
      t=t+pow(r,2);
      q=q/10;
 }
 while(q%10!=0);
 printf("%d",t);
 getch();


}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `while(q%10!=0);` be something like `while(q>0);`? Otherwise it'll stop at a `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your stopping condition is wrong: `q%10!=0` will become "true" as soon as you reach the first zero in a decimal representation. For example, for a number `6540321` your program would add 3<sup>2</sup>+2<sup>2</sup>+1<sup>2</sup>, and stop, because the next digit happens to be zero. Squares of 6, 5, and 4 would never be added.

Use `q != 0` condition instead to fix this problem. In addition, consider replacing

```
t=t+pow(r,2);
```

with a more concise and C-like

```
t += r*r;
```

Comment: why is pow if not written makes code more c like? @dasblinkenlight

Comment: @SUMITKUMARSINGHDIXIT It's `+=` that makes it more C-like, not the absence of `pow`. Dropping `pow` makes it more concise.

Comment: Would there be slower performance when using `pow(r,2)` rather than `r*r`?

Comment: @CoolGuy I doubt it: chances are that any decent optimizer would produce identical code for the three expressions (i.e. the one in OP, my expression, and `t += pow(r,2);` expression). It is mostly a readability thing these days.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
while(q%10!=0);
```

To

```
while(q);
```

Which is the short for

```
while(q!=0);
```

This is done to prevent to loop from ending once the value of `q` is a multiple of 10.